# Remove specific text from Excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, string, row, multiple-columns

I'm doing a project and I need to remove some specific text from a string . For example, from these strings I would like to remove the numbers in the end (_230; _0 ; _240) until the '__' .

'KSS_10292_TRIPLEBAND_230' , 'ATR451606_0', 'K_80010510V01_240'

I'm using python and these strings are in a Excel column named 'AntennaReference'.

Comment: What do you mean by "until the '__'" ?

Comment: starting in the end until the underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rsplit` function which returns a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.([More here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit))

Complete code looks like this:

```
test_string = "KSS_10292_TRIPLEBAND_230"
splited_list = test_string.rsplit("_", 1) # ['KSS_10292_TRIPLEBAND', '230']
splited_string = splited_list[0] # KSS_10292_TRIPLEBAND
```

Or in one line:

```
"KSS_10292_TRIPLEBAND_230".rsplit("_", 1)[0]
```